# Retrieve all task names from a task list

Tags: 2013, document-library, filter, task-list

I have created a task list and a document library. I try to connect these so that it filters the same data at the same time

In my document library I have a lookup-column that retrieves the task name, so that I can link the tasks in the task-list with the documents. I then use a "HTML Form Web Part" to sort out the task/documents i want.

Everything works as intended. Unfortunately, there is a big disadvantage to this solution. I must manually update the "HTML Form Web Part" every time a new task is entered.

Is there any way to automatically retrieve the names from the task list. similar to what the lookup columns does.

Comment: I just read you question again.  It occurred to me that I should mention that you can apply a filter to any list or document library - for instance if you want to set up a view for users so that the task list will filter only on their tasks, do this:  create view -> filter -> e.g. Show the items when column "Assigned To" "is equal to" "[Me]"  (FIELD / OPERATOR / VALUE)

Answer (score 0):

What purpose does the task list serve?  Is it for document approval?  If so, you could use [content approval](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08) instead, this would remove the need for a separate task list.  Here is a good instruction from a blogger I follow: [How to approve documents without building a workflow](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-approve-documents-without-building-a-workflow/).  You can also customise document approval to have several approvers (layers of management or approvers from different departments).

I realise I am making some assumptions as to the purpose of your task list.  If your task list is to track and follow up tasks i.e. nothing to do with Document Approval, then could consider creating a custom workflow using Sharepoint Designer (it is free to download from MS).  The workflow could be used to create tasks in your task list and can be configured to copy over certain fields/properties from your document library.

### Updated - (Connections)

You could try this.

First - edit one of your views on the Document Library and add a web part to display your Task List on the same page.  This will result in both your Document Library & Task List being displayed on the same page.  Next you'll need to filter them -> imagine your Doc Library is above and Task List is below.

Next - add a Connection.  Edit page -> edit a web part e.g. Document Library.  Select "Connections" (see pictures).  You can 'hook up' a connection between a field which is found in both the Doc Library and the Task List.

In Picture 2 you can define which fields are used - what you're doing here is configuring a filter between the Doc Library and the Task list.

In Picture 3 you'll see there is a new 'Select' field.  If you test this field, you might find that you need to click select on the Document Library (to select the Project), then the Task list will filter on this.

You might find it tricky to configure the connection, it does work, I've found that it sometimes takes a while to find the correct field to create the connection.

If it does not work, try this:  use the Select field AND filter on a column in your Project name as well.

Picture.1
[image]

Picture.2
[image]

Picture.3
[image]

Comment: The task list will be used to keep track of various projects. There is nothing to be approved. Instead of creating pages and views for each project, I use 1 tasklist and 1 document library. To sort among all projects, I use a dropdown list created with HTML Form Web part. But as I tried to explain above, I have to manually enter the data in the dropdown list to be able to be selected and sorted. e.g. I select "Project x" in the dropdown list. This allows the task list and documents the library sorts and displays only those files.

Comment: What you describe in your solution, is the way I am already doing it. The difference is that I also use a dropdown list to filter (instead of your picture 3). This dropdown must be manually updated every time a new task is entered. I wanted to find a solution that does it automatically

Comment: Hmmm, I believe the method I've described means the latest data is always available automatically.  It avoids the manual steps you describe.

Comment: You are correct that it works and updates by it self. The problem is that in my opinion its not a user friendly solution/interface. Its hard to find where to click (weird icon as well) and if you select something you have to refresh the page to see all tasks again. A dropdown or even better a cascading dropdown is much more user friendly.